# How to change premium capacity into normal capacity in the powerBI workspace with the help of powershell script

Tags: powershell, powerbi

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount

$data = Import-Csv -Path C:\powershell\UnassignWorkspace.csv

$data | forEach
{
$URI = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/"+$_.WorkspaceID+"/AssignToCapacity"

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $URI -Method AssignToCapacity
{
    capacityId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
}
```

-----This is the right code, if it is not then please write a code.

please do it fast

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount

$data = Import-Csv -Path C:\powershell\UnassignWorkspace.csv

$data | forEach
{
$URI = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/"+$_.WorkspaceID+"/AssignToCapacity"

**Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $URI -Method AssignToCapacity
{
capacityId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
}

**

Comment: Have you tried out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here there are several code errors. As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/capacities/groups-assign-to-capacity), this is a Post request. If you are not using a Service Principle you must have admin privileges.

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount

$header = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
$body = @{
    capacityId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}

$data = Import-Csv -Path C:\powershell\UnassignWorkspace.csv

$data | forEach
{
$URI = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/"+$_.WorkspaceID+"/AssignToCapacity"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Method POST -Headers $header -Body $body

}
```

Accept my answer and upvote please

Comment: i have tried this code it's working on my only my workspace ,but i want to change the  premium capacity to normal capacity which is publicly assign by me.

Comment: Reason is you don't have power bi global admin privilage.